# How can I call only the second string in this Map Double Double?

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

This is how I pull data from Google Sheets:

```
Map<double, double> m = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2)).map((
    key, value) =>
    MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));
```

How can I ignore the key and pull only the values as strings?

Comment: Check out [`Map.values`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_map_values.htm). But this brings up the question, why do you store it in a `Map` in the first place, if you need only the values? You could use an array instead and just `map` your results to their `value`s. Do you need the keys elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`values`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Map/values.html) property for the `Map` class. This returns an `Iterable` of all the values in the `Map`. You can then use the `toList` method to get a `List` if that's preferable. Example:

```dart
List list = m.values.toList();
```